# How to load phtml file in checkout/onepage payment information section

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, phtml

I'm trying to load `epayment.phtml` file in `checkout/onepage` payment information section.

Page can't loaded in  `checkout/onepage` payment information section.

this is my code.

`app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml`

```
<!-- load epatment page-->
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('epayment/index.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
<!-- load epatment page-->
```

Epayment.xml:
`app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\layout\epayment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <epayment_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="epayment/index" name="epayment_index" template="epayment/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </epayment_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Comment: Which theme and checkout extension are you using

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala: Am using coolbaby theme and checkout extension in default.

Comment: can you give me checkout url I need to check frontname and all

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala: Sorry bro it is in local server

Comment: When am access `epayment.phtml` url directly (http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/sliver-exchange/epayment)  `checkout/onepage `payment information section `epayment.phtml` Block showing

Answer (score 1):

Change your `app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml` like below

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('epayment/index')->setTemplate('epayment/index.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Comment: If am directly access 127.0.0.1/ramesh/sliver-exchange/epayment , epayment.phtml loaded in `payment information` section. Otherwise not loading